# the density of the sum of $n$ random variables with uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $X_n$ be an iid sequence of random variable with uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$. Using characteristic functions prove that $X_1+X_2+...+X_n$ has density

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty}{(\frac{\sin(t)}{t})^n \cos(tx)dt}$$

I proved that the characteristic function of $X_n$ is $\phi(t)= (\frac{\sin(t)}{t}) $ Thus the characteristic function of $S_n$ is $(\frac{\sin(t)}{t})^n $

I don't know how this could work. Please help me!

Comment: Shouldn't you now apply the inverse Fourier transform to get the pdf from the characteristic function?

Comment: Try to find the characteristic function of $X$, where $X$ has the density $f$. You get your $\phi$ then you have finished.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the characteristic function of $X_1+\dots+X_n$ is indeed $\left(\frac{\sin t}t\right)^n$. The [inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas) for an integrable characteristic function ($n\geqslant 2$) will give the result (cut the integral $\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^\infty$ and use the substitution $s=-t$ in the first integral).