# Show that $S_n = X_1+ \cdots X_n $ the probability density function $f_{s{_n}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We consider $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$ a probability space and $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables such that $X_1 \sim \operatorname{Unif}(-1,1)$. Show that $S_n = X_1+ \cdots X_n $ for $n \ge 2$ has  the probability density function $$f_{s{_n}} = \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \Bigg(\frac{\sin(t)}{t} \bigg)^n \cos(xt)dt $$

I have found out that I could use that $|\frac{\sin(t)}{t}|\le1$ for $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ and I have also calculated that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \Bigg(\frac{\sin(t)}{t} \bigg)^2 dt = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ At this point I have no clue how should I continue it I would really appreciate any kind of help since I'm learning the topics on my own.

Comment: If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are any independent r.v.s with probability distributions $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$, then the probability distribution of their sum is the convolution $\mu_1*\dots*\mu_n$. For the rest, just use the Fourier transform.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3615897/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characteristic function of $S_n$ is
$$\phi_{S_n}(t) = E[e^{itS_n}] = \prod_{k=1}^n E[e^{itX_k}] = \left(\frac{e^{it} - e^{-it}}{2it}\right)^n = \left(\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)^n.$$

The [inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formula) shows how you can compute the density $f_{S_n}$ if you know the characteristic function $\phi_{S_n}$.

\begin{align}
f_{S_n}(x)
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-itx} \phi_{S_n}(t) \, dt
\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-itx} \phi_{S_n}(t) \, dt + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{iux} \phi_{S_n}(-u) \, du
& u = -t
\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty (e^{itx} + e^{-itx}) \phi_{S_n}(t) \, dt
& \phi_{S_n}(-t) = \phi_{S_n}(t)
\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \cos(tx) \phi_{S_n}(t) \, dt.
\end{align}

Comment: $\frac{1}{\pi}$ makes more sense than $\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

Characteristic function will work.  Ley $f(x)$ be density function for $X_k$.  $\phi(t)=\int_R e^{itx}f(x)dx$.  Then density function for $S$ is given by $f_S(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_R e^{-itx}\phi^n(t)dt$.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I really don't know how can I get the density function could maybe someone help me a bit in this part? May a little bit more detailed way could make me clear how does it work exactly. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Wikipedia has a detailed discussion of characteristic function.